# Unable to send ajax json post request to django view

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am trying send json using ajax

Ajax :

```
$.ajax({
                 type:"POST",
                 url:"../create_folder/",
                 data: {
                        //csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
                        sharedfolder // from form
                        },
                        contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        debugger;
        $("#folder_create").dialog('close');
        $("#folder-details").pqGrid("refreshDataAndView" );
    },
    error: function(data){
        debugger;
        alert("fail");

            }
        });
            return false;
```

To a view :

```
@csrf_exempt
def create_folder(request):
  c = {}
  c.update(csrf(request))
  data = request.POST["sharedfolder"]
  print type(data)
  return HttpResponse(sf,content_type="application/type")
```

I get this error :

> MultiValueDictKeyError at /create_folder/ "'sharedfolder'" Request
>   Method:   GET Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/create_folder/ Django
>   Version:  1.6.1 Exception Type:   MultiValueDictKeyError Exception
>   Value:     "'sharedfolder'" Exception
>   Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py
>   in **getitem**, line 301 Python Executable:   /usr/bin/python Python
>   Version:  2.7.6 Python Path:
>   ['/home/celestial/Documents/celestial_NAS',  '/usr/lib/python2.7', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
>   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client'] Server
>   time: Sun, 26 Jul 2015 10:30:24 +0000

WHAT COULD BE THE MISTAKE?

Comment: it seeme you are getting `GET` request to server ?

Comment: can you please provide form ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be correctly passing in the `sharedfolder` parameter to the AJAX script, so when you try to access it with `data = request.POST["sharedfolder"]` you get the Key Exception error.

Normally when using the `data` property on an AJAX call you would use key-value pairs, such as

```
sharedfolder: sharedfoldervalue
```

where `sharedfoldervalue` is obtained from the form submission.

Comment: this is my sharefolder json

Comment: {
 "sharedFolder":
 {
  "sharedFolderName" :"test1",
  "ownerName"  :"amit",
  "volumeName"  :"temp",
  "description"  :"This is only description section",
  "uniqueID"  :"0",
  "public"  :"yes",
  "services":
  {
   "wiki"   :"yes",
   "cifs"   :"yes",
   "ftp"   :"yes",
   "nfs"   :"yes",
   "rb"   :"yes",
   "ms"   :"yes",
   "afp"   :"yes",
   "webdav"  :"yes",
   "encrypt"  :"yes"
  },
  "backup":
  {
   "rName":"test2",
   "rPasswd":"testing2"
  }
 }
}

Comment: changes i did data: 
data:    {
                        //csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
                        sf : sharedfolder // from form
                        },
in views.py 
data = request.POST.get('sf')

now i get error like:
NameError at /create_folder/
global name 'sf' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not posting via `AJAX`.I mean here is `GET` request in your traceback.So `request.POST` will be `{}`.Thats why you are getting this error.So check

```
<form >
whatever
<button type="submit"> or even no type attribute
</form>
```

Change above to

```
<button type="button">
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error some days ago.

Use request.POST.get("sharedfolder") insted of request.POST["sharedfolder"]